# Application crashes when using NSMutableString

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

in a header file I defined

```
NSMutableArray *numbers;
```

In the implementation I initialize this array first in the init method

```
numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

I add strings to this array

```
[numbers insertObject:number atIndex:[numbers count]];
```

But when I access the array like this in another method

```
NSLog(@"%@", [numbers count]);
```

the application crashes. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong here -

```
NSLog(@"%@", [numbers count]);
```

Array count is an integer value. Use %d instead of %@ to print integer.

```
NSLog(@"%d", [numbers count]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your format string doesn't match the type of the second parameter.

`[numbers count]` returns an integer, not an object.

The " %@" format specifier indicates that the corresponding argument is an object, and that object will be sent a -description message.  The string returned from that message expression will be inserted in place of the "%@".  Your app crashes because it tries to send a message to  an invalid receiver.